# Discord.py how to recognize user from text

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to write a little game with discord bot, but I need somehow my BOT to recognize user mentioned in message content (without actual mention, just string of current nick on server)

So there will be message like this
!command nick (without mention)

Then I am spliting this message in code and geting nick in variable as a string. Now I need bot to find out, if there is a user by this nickname and respond and mentioning the user.

```
if msg.startswith('!'):
    komand,tex = msg.split(" ")
    victim = tex #here I need some code to make it user id or nickname so I could mention it later
    await message.channel.send('@{} blablabla.'.format(victim))
    #next I want to check if user is on server(and online) and possibly let him use different command to response again.
```

Thanks for any help. Hope it's not much confusing. I know there is something like commands in discord.py, but I am not prepared to transform whole current bot to bot.commands, so I am checking commands manually for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Guild.get_member_named()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild.get_member_named) method to access a member by name. Discord will lookup the user within the guild (server) via username or nickname. For example:

```
guild:Optional[discord.Guild] = message.guild
if guild is not None:
    member:Optional[discord.Member] = guild.get_member_named(username)
```

You can then send your response at [member.mention](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.mention).

```
if member is not None:
    await message.channel.send(f'Hello {member.mention} this is a test.')
else:
    # Handle user not found
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try it tomorrow. One more question..

So then will this works? 
await message.channel.send(f"{member.mention} is a player")

and how could I use it in if then? 
if message.author == ???:

Comment: @MužZvanýKůň I've updated the post to include `mention` response details. The `if` statement format would depend on what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: Check if the next command is from a member mentioned before